References for multifractal complex measures?
I am learning about multifractal formalism recently. It seems nearly all the work is done for real-valued measures.

Question: I am wondering whether there is study (or even definition!) for multifractal formalism of complex measures.

By complex measures I am refering to complex-valued measures (as defined in this wikipedia page) intead of complicated measures (which seems to be what a google serach of 'multifractal complex measures' will lead to).
